# Old fantasy movie in color (russian?) princess with a lot of sisters (10-12 maybe) meets a guy and runs away with him, story includes a blue flower

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie is an old fantasy movie in color (not black and white) about a princess that has a bunch of sisters (10-12 I think).
I watched it in Russian in 2015-2019, so it is either a Russian one or one that comes in Russian dub, but it is certainly much older and may be from around 1930-2000.

The princess meets a guy that I think was on the hunt for some magical blue flower (I think it supposedly granted a long or maybe even eternal life) and they find it together. Later in the story they run away together but her father manages to catch her, and when the guy who she was running away with finds out that she was taken he goes to save her.
He meets her father standing in the middle of a circular white room with a bunch of smaller "rooms" on the sides of the round one, each containing one of the 10-12 princesses (including the main character). The father tells the guy to pick a room where he thinks the right princess is: if he gets it right he gets to leave with her, otherwise he dies (or something like that). I am pretty sure he got it wrong but the father did not kill him.
Instead, he offered him to choose between two potions (a black one and a white one) and told him that one of them would kill him and the other would not, so he had to pick one and drink it. I think that the safe potion (the one that would not kill the guy) came from some sort of little fountain. Pretty sure this time he choose the right one so he survived and escaped with the princess he came for or something.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, does it include any explicit science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: @LogicDictates hi, i watched it somwhere around 2015-2019 but it is certianly much older i think that the movie itself may be from around 1930-2000. As for the fantasy aspect i remember the movie including some magic blue flower that i think supposedly granted a long or maybe even eternal life and the two potions the black and the white one, I also think that the safe potion (as in the one that would not kill the guy) came from some sort of little fountain. Hope that clarified it :)

Comment: Please update the question itself to include those details. You should also remove the [fantasy-genre] tag, as that's only for general questions about the fantasy genre, not for questions about specific works, like this one. You can edit the title or body of the question to mention that it involves fantasy elements, though.

Comment: @LogicDictates hi, i am seeing that the fantasy genre tag has also gotten removed and i apologize for the mistake.

Comment: No apology needed. It's an easy mistake to make for someone who is new to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a bit like The Thief of Bagdad - this scene might let you decide

This is the 1961 version starring Steve Reeves, and to the best of my knowledge, the only one that includes a blue rose as part of the story.

Comment: You could greatly improve this answer by explaining how _The Thief of Bagdad_ matches the film described in the question. That video could get taken down at some point, in which case there'd be no immediate way of knowing why you think this might be the correct answer. It would also be good to specify (in text) which version of _The Thief of Bagdad_ you have in mind, since there are multiple versions (1924, 1940, 1977).

Comment: @slywlf54 I will definetely be checking it out, thank you so much for the help.